# how could I do when faced with "leader=-1" error in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I set up a Kafka application which has 2 brokers and create a topic which has 3 partitions,the replication factor=1.
Then I use producer process to send data.when producer is running,I kill one of the 3 brokers and producer process gave out the following message:

**kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3 tries.**

If data losss is allowed,how could I do to make producer process recover automaticlly.
I think the best solution is that move the partition in the deleted broker to another 2 brokers.
How could I do?
If not,does it just mean that there is no way to recover when faced with leader=-1?

note:
In my situation,replicaion factor is set 1 for reducing bandwidth utilization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html

> For a topic with replication factor N, we will tolerate up to N-1
>   server failures without losing any messages committed to the log.

So if you want to have automatic failover - increase replication factor.

Comment: could I do failover manully via monitor script if I have to set replication factor=1.thanks very much.

Comment: You need to reassign your partition to another broker. Try this: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_cluster_expansion kafka-reassign-partitions.sh

Comment: I have read the documentation  you advise,but I am confused that when running the reassignment tool,any producers and consumers can not work,does not it?They can not work until reassignment tool has finished?

Comment: When you lose node with N=1 you can't read/write to corresponding partitions on that node anyway. So you have only 2 options: fix node or do reassignment(and lose all data). My suggestion: use N>1 - it's much simpler. It's hard to achieve full network utilization in datacenters.

Comment: your answer helps me a lot.Thanks very much.